# Android folder error in flutter new project

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/270Hs.png)[image]

Whenever I create a new Flutter project and run the project this error always appears.
These Android folder errors do not cause any problems but are noticeable.
How can I solve this type of error?

Comment: What is the error message/ stack trace?

Comment: The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Process 'command '/Users/hafizurrahman/VsCode-flutter/we_chat/android/gradlew'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Process 'command '/Users/hafizurrahman/VsCode-flutter/we_chat/android/gradlew'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.